# Ubuntu 15.04 Wacom Intuos Draw not workig, any help?

Tags: drivers, 15.04, tablet, wacom

I'm kinda new to Ubuntu and need some help.

My Intuos Draw tablet isn't working properly.
I installed the driver through the Linux Wacom Tablet Project and now it draws, recognizes pressure and all, but I can't configure the buttons from the Wacom app on System Settings, it says that there's no device plugged in (even though it draws and everything).
I'd like to be able to configure the buttons, any help will come in hand.

Thank you, fellas!

Comment: I use Krita (work related), so I would need to configure the buttons for actions like undo, zoom... GIMP and Inkscape already have built in configuration for tablets, but I'd need to do then anyway. So help me, please, Internet wizards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You might need to update libwacom:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Downloads

2. Or you might need to update your kernel driver (same link)
3. Quite possibly both